# All content in my table appear in one column only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jsfiddle application which you can access [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8hNwG/36/). Now when you open the application, please type in a question in the textarea on top and please select an option by clicking on "Option" and selecting one of the 2 options. Once you have done this then click on the "Add Question" button.

You will see you details outputted in the table below. The problem is however that since I made the table below a scrollable table with fixed headers, all of the content appears in the first row only "Question No". This content you have added should go under 5 columns "Question No", Question", "Option type", "Number of Answers" and "Answer".

So what my question is that why is all of the content appear under one column only and how can this be fixed? Please use the fiddle to test your code.

To see the table scroll bar, after you typed in your question and select an option then just keep clicking on the "Add Question" button in output rows until you see the table scrollbar on the side.

Comment: Are you Mashrafe Mostafa again, or another sock of [BruceyBandit?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1096892)  Why did you make another account?  I'd sure like to know why this is happening.  Are you one of two-dozen students from the same classroom in London asking about the same homework assignment?

Comment: I am Mashrafe, I made another account because I forgot my login details for the other account. I am using university computer so it doesn't save my login details. What do you mean by another sock of BruceyBandit? I am from Aston by the way not London

Comment: Are you part of a class that was given a homework assignment, and asked to fulfill it by asking questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is a web assignment for my Web Development final year. There is people doing same assignment, why you asking?

Comment: We have been given references to online help if we are struggling such as stackoverflow, codingforums, webdevelopers and so on.

Comment: Because BruceyBandit has 22 merged accounts, and about 80 complaints from users on Stack Overflow.  All total, about 290 questions have been asked about this same homework assignment.  It has become very disruptive to the site.

Comment: Teacher just mentioned on lecture slides some online help for web programmers. Lecturer never told us to abuse the site or do anything like this, 80 complaints! I am guessing he is very unpopular on your site

Comment: I don't think it's just him; I think it was 22 people from your class, and I mistook them for a single person creating new accounts to get around the two-year ban I imposed.  It is a problem if I am correct, because 22 people now have banned accounts.  I'd like to solve this in some reasonable way, if I can.

Comment: Do you have an email address for your teacher?  I'd like to contact him, if I can.  Don't worry, I'll be nice. :)

Comment: Well it cant be 22 people in the class because there is about 15 people in our class, I know some of my work mates are using stackoverflow in university for help on their assignments but they have not mentioned anything about being banned or anything. It maybe just some individuals abusing this site. Problem is though that I don't know anyone in our class known as Bruce so I don't know where BruceyBandit comes from

Comment: His name's not Bruce; I don't know what his real name is, but he goes by the alternate name of Mayur Patel.

Comment: I do have email address for our teacher. Email Address u0867587@hud.ac.uk and his name is Dr Martyn Reed. Hopefully you can solve this problem and glad I could help

Comment: Thank you.  I will follow up with Dr. Reed.

Comment: There is no Mayur Patel in our class but there is a Manesh Patel in our class, it could be him but I can't be sure

Comment: Do you want me to give names of students I know in our class, see if there is any person you recognise from one of the accounts?

Comment: No, that's all right; we're verging into privacy territory now.  Tell your professor I will be contacting him, and refer him to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117611.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just saw the link you just provided, this person is definetly unpopular and abusing the site as mentioned in one of the answers, I hope this problem is fixed and I feel sorry for the situation your website has suffered. Hopefully this matter can be resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't jam divs into tables. Content goes inside of `<td>`s or `<th>`s [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/8hNwG/39/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: If what you're really interested in is a fixed header, then there are many solutions available. The first one I tried was [table fixed header](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/) a jQuery plugin

```
$('#qandatbl').fixheadertable({height: '200'});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hNwG/46/)

Comment: So my problem is that how can I make the table scrollable with fixed table headings? That is actually the reason why I included the div's. I have used couple of examples but I do not know how to implement it on my table?

Comment: it looks like it works but the columns look a bit messy, is this because of the fiddle? I never used a jquery plugin before for scrolling table, I always tried to do it by scrath